# Jira Summary contains text filter

Tags: jira, jql

I need to filter issues whose title (Summary attribute?) contains a text "`config`". So what I did is:

1. More->Summary
2. Enter the text "`config`"

But for some reason I only got issues whose title contains "`config`" or "`configs`". I didn't get the issues whose title contains e.g. "`configuration`". What's wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this JQL for your filter:

```
summary ~ "config*"
```

The wildcard should help pick up `config` as well as extensions like `configuration` and `configs`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! But what's the reason of the original problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: @embedc if you click `Advanced` after trying your original steps, you'll see that the JQL generated for your search is `summary ~ config order by lastViewed DESC`. It might be a good feature request for Atlassian to add the `*` wildcard to these searches by default to prevent confusion.

Comment: The `~` operator is not really a "contains" operator though in the conventional sense, so behavior can be very unexpected when using a text string containing multiple words. It's more of a "contains one or more of the words in any order" operator. If I run `summary ~ "Some Random Text"` then Jira returns a ticket with the summaries "Some Other Stuff" and "This One Random" issue.

Comment: yep - still waiting for https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-21372 to be addressed...